# Accented characters read from file has different value under Eclipse than console

Tags: java, eclipse, windows

I'm trying to match a dropdown option:

```
Cabina Económica
```

against a String imported from a properties file.

I was having problems using

```
"//a[text()='" + cabin + "']"
```

and so changed it to:

```
final String translateFrom = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÄÖÜÉÈÊÀÁÂÒÓÔÙÚÛÇÅÏÕÑŒäöüéèêàáâòóôùúûçåïõñœ";
final String translateTo   = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzaoueeeaaaooouuucaionoaoueeeaaaooouuucaiono";
"//a[translate(text(),'"+translateFrom+"','"+translateTo+"')=translate('"+cabin+"', '"+translateFrom+"', '"+translateTo+"')]";
```

which works perfectly when I test it in Eclipse, but fails when I run it under the Windows 7 console:

```
main() Terminating due to error/exception: Unable to locate element: ....)=translate('Cabina Econ├│mica'....
```

If I print out the dropdown option from the page, under the Windows console it show as:

```
Cabina Econ≤mica
```

≤ seems to be ASCII F3, which matches what I see when I examine the (both) Strings under Eclipse.

But ├│, the value being read from the properties file, whilst it is F3 under Eclipse, seems to be C3B3 under the Windows console.

F3 is the Unicode value for ó; C3B3 is its UTF-8 value.

Why does reading the properties file under Eclipse (via Spring) give a different result to reading it under the Windows console, and what do I need to do to make these equal?

### Update

The webpage I'm reading is defined with

```
<meta ... charset=utf-8>
```

so I assume that something (Selenium?) is translating it to utf-16 or utf-32 (where ó = x'f3') before I see it.

Whereas Spring's property file seems to being read as utf-8 under the console but 16/32 under Eclipse.

### Update 2

Further research suggest this might be something to do with Spring's property file loading.  I've opened a new question at:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35612302/spring-loads-property-files-differently-under-windows-console-than-under-eclipse

and think it best to delete this one (unless anyone objects?)

Answer (score 2):

Check the encoding of the console in the preference of eclipse. It's probably not the same encoding used by the windows console.

Comment: Isn't that an output issue?  I don't mind (much...) that Windows is displaying me ASCII characters, I just need its INPUTS to match.

Comment: Note that a 'console' type window in Windows is not the same thing as the console pane in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Uncertain but possible answer with info:

Actually nothing above 7F is ASCII; a Windows console window (often inaccurately called 'DOS' prompt or window) uses the [Windows 'OEM' (legacy) code page usually 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) in which F3 is the character `≤`. And the two characters `├│` are C3 B3 which you correctly identify as the UTF-8 for Unicode F3 `ó`. It is possible to fix the Windows console display by explicitly encoding to `IBM437`, but you need to do this *only* for the console display and not elsewhere, including not Windows *files* because files use either the so-called 'ANSI' (really CP1252) single-byte code or one of several Unicode encodings (UTF-8 or UTF-16 in either endianness).

Java's *default* encoding for I/O (particularly but not only files) on Windows is CP1252, while on Unix it is often though not always UTF-8. Is your Eclipse on Unix? My Eclipse (Indigo) on Windows defaults CP1252 for plain Java, but I don't know if Spring does anything to override that. *If* it uses the default to read your file, you can set that default with system property `file.encoding=utf-8`.

Comment: Thanks for this Dave.  No, both are on Windows.  I agree this looks like something to do with Spring's handling of property files.  I've opened a new question specifically for that.  I suspect I should delete this one, yes?